# How to avoid multiple login for an account which is already opened

Tags: vb.net

How to avoid  multiple login for same account? (for both standalone & multiple system via DB)

Once I login to  a project (Using SQL DB) & Minimize that (after login form).

Running that same project in another ms vital studio, Trying to login the same account which is already logged in.

I want to get error as `User Has Already Logged In`, How can I do that?

Comment: In the database, you add a new column called `loggedIn` or anything like that, this should have a value 0 as default, but when the user is trying to login, if the user exist, you check for this value if it's 0, that's mean that no one is logged in so you log him in and change that value to 1, and when he log out you change it again to 0.

Comment: format and details

Comment: The real question you have to answer is... What does it mean to be "logged in"? Eg if I log in and sit idle, how long is my session considered valid? If I don't explicitly log out, what happens? Once you've got a process in place to handle session management (track when a session was created, has been kept alive and should expire with no further activity), checking if a session already exists for a user becomes trivial. One approach is to I have a table of active sessions, with an `ExpiresOn` field that's updated every time a user makes a request

Comment: In simple words , no buddy should allow to login once I login to an account until I logout or close that particular project .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple words , no buddy should allow to login once I login to an account until I logout or close that particular project .

Comment: Restrict the same user to login from different machines in vb